# Padding On Tablet Device

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, css

I'm developing a website that has custom lightboxes.  When the user activates a lightbox, there is a gray translucent div that comes behind the active lightbox.  I've noticed on tablets (ios and android) there is about a 10 pixel margin on the right side where a scrollbar would be.  I've tried the following CSS and it hasn't removed it:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #gray_out {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
  }
}

html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
```

Here is what it looks like on a desktop:

> [image]

Here is what it looks like on a tablet:

> [image]

Notice the bright yellow sliver.

The code for the div that provides the graying:

```
z-index: 99999;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74902);
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width: 802px;
height: 2034px;
position: absolute;
top: -0.00006103515625px;
```

The top value is generated with jQuery.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I can't provide a direct link to the site, and for this situation jsFiddle can't help because of the nature of the issue.  Bear with me.

Comment: So your question is: "How do i remove this 10 pixel margin on tablet browsers?"

Comment: Correct, not sure how I missed asking the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems obvious in hindsight, maybe there is a more elegant solution but eventually this is what I came up with:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #gray_out {
    margin-left: -20px ;
    margin-right: -20px;
    width: 105%;
  }

    #home_footer, #home_header, #home_row_1, #home_row_2, #home_row_3 {
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
        width: 102%;
    }
}
```

Removing padding/margins wouldn't work, and that 10px sliver was actually interfering with more than the gray div, so I just made everything that much wider on mobile devices.  I've tested it on a couple different versions of the iPad and a handful of Android devices on browserstack and it seems to be working well enough.